# Transfer Maven local repository to another PC

Tags: java, maven

I have local maven repository that also contains 3rd party libraries created in not Maven way. I would like to have same repository in several PC's. What is the best way of doing that? Probably one of the ways is just copy `.m2` directory (not sure about consequences). What is the right way of using identical maven repositories in several PC's?

Comment: As weird as it may sound, once you start using words like `sharing` or `copying`, you should start thinking of a repository manager, see https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html. Installing shouldn't be that hard and the advantages are worth it.

Comment: Is there any free repository manager services available? Like Bitbucket for git.

Comment: This would be an own question, but there are three Repo Managers I can think of right now: Artefactory (Bintray), Nexus (from Sonatype) and Archiva (Apache Foundation). I know that at least Nexus provides a free license. The same is true for Archiva.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you to create a Central Repository in one of your network PC and then create a  `settings.xml` file and place it in the `C:\Users\<username>\.m2` in all the PC's in the LAN.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>C:\Common_Workspace\Repository\.m2</localRepository> <!--Central Repository in the organization -->
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

So, whenever you add a new dependency in your project, it will get downloaded from [Maven Central Repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/) to the location specified within the `<localRepository>` tag. In our organization we share a common RTC repository from where we add and retrieve dependencies.